# application cache & 404/500 pages

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, html5-appcache, application-cache

I have a manifest that looks somethin like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# e4a75fb378cb627a0d51a80c1cc5684c2d918d93e267f5854a511aa3c8db5b1a
/a/application.js
/a/application.css

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/ /offline/redirect
```

The issue is that my /404.html and /500.html pages (that are obviously served up with a response code of 404 and 500) are triggering the fallback.  They both act just as if the server is offline.

My question is twofold:

1. Why does /404.html trigger the fallback when /events doesn't?
2. How can I allow /404.html and /500.html to not trigger the fallback while still allowing / to

trigger it.

For what it's worth, I've already tried this:

```
NETWORK:
*
/404.html
/500.html
```

... however since those pages are served w/ a non-200 response code, it triggers the app cache error callback and the cache isn't saved.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, it's not just 404 and 500 pages, it's ANY route/method/action/whatever that returns a 400+ response code.  So, something like /teams/1241231 where that 'team' doesn't exist, should render a 404 pages w/ a 404 code - but it's picked up by the FALLBACK.

Comment: Hi. Have you finally managed to get a solution for this? I'm having the same issue: obtaining fallback page as response when I should receive a 403. Suggested workaround of 'always return 200' is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

- Remove * from the NETWORK declaration
- Redirect to /404.html (et al) instead of rendering in place.

So using the example above:  `/teams/1241231` 302 redirect to `/404.html` which returns a 404 status code.